# Do arxiv moderators not work on Sundays?

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv

I have noticed one thing that whenever I submit a paper in arxiv  on Friday, they keep "on hold" from  Saturday to Sunday and then accept it later Monday or Tuesday.  On the other hand, it happened that when I submit a paper during Monday, Tuesday etc,  then process of submission becomes much faster. On Sunday and Saturday, the system seems to stop.

Thus: do the arxiv moderators not work on Sundays?

Comment: Grad student in disbelief: "Do some people really not work on weekends? How is that possible??" :D

Comment: You should assume that most business processes requiring human action will not occur over the weekend or on holidays in the country where the business is located. Even if the business is of substantial size and does have 24/7/365 support and action, it will still often have reduced capability during off-hours and/or off-days where customer interaction might be supplied by a second tier of support and not have available the more complete range of options available to the first tier of workers, who are usually working close to the normal business hours in the company's primary location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does arXiv have a multi-day lag between submission and publication?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/159785/why-does-arxiv-have-a-multi-day-lag-between-submission-and-publication)

Comment: @Szabolcs Felicitous remark, however, regarding the factual core, in other countries/traditions there might be no entirely work-free weekend or it might be other days than saturday and Christian sunday.

Comment: @TripeHound, I don't think that is same  question as mine. It has a subtle difference.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR The questions may not be exactly the same, but the answers there seem to apply to both questions.

Comment: @TripeHound, My purpose of asking the question was clearly different than the OP's purpose in the other question. The OP was asking the `reason` which I am not asking. I agree with you that the answers of  one (either mine or OP's) question to some extent covers both questions but my question is different and we should let it as separate question without creating any confusion.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, arXiv staff are not working on weekends. They also do not work on major [holidays](https://arxiv.org/new) in the USA.

Answer (score 25):

The exact times when preprints go online depending on when they are submitted are documented in detail on the [website](https://arxiv.org/help/availability). There is also [this](https://arxiv.org/localtime) site showing the time until the next deadline.